# Array of hashes laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

Using Laravel 4.2
Have the  below datastructure retrieved by using Eloquent queries.

```
[
  {
      Id: 1,
      Product:Test1,
      TypeId:100
   }
     {
      Id: 2,
      Product:Test2,
      TypeId:200
   }
      {
      Id: 3,
      Product:Test2,
      TypeId:200
   }
];
```

Want to  create a hash map based on TypeId as key so I can search the products easily.  Want the final output below way

```
{
      '100' :  {
          Id: 1,
          Product:Test1,
          TypeId:100
       },
       '200' : [

                     {
          Id: 2,
          Product:Test2,
          TypeId:200
       },
          {
          Id: 3,
          Product:Test2,
          TypeId:200
       }


       ]
}
```

Tried the below eloquent function but duplicates in the Type Id 200 are ignored.
$type_id_hash=$fm->fmmodelitems->keyBy('TypeId');

For typeid 200 only one record exists when using keyby function as it ignore duplicates.   I want to search array of hashmap for a key like typeid.   How can it be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want [`groupBy` on `Collection`](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_groupBy):

```
$grouped = $fm->fmmodelitems->groupBy('TypeId');
```

This should group them under that 'key'.

```
$collection = new Illuminate\Support\Collection([
    ['Id' => 1, 'Product' => 'Test1', 'TypeId' => 100],
    ['Id' => 2, 'Product' => 'Test2', 'TypeId' => 200],
    ['Id' => 3, 'Product' => 'Test3', 'TypeId' => 200]
]);

$grouped = $collection->groupBy('TypeId');

$grouped->all();

// array(
//   100 => array(
//     0 => array(
//       'Id' => 1,
//       'Product' => 'Test1',
//       'TypeId' => 100
//     )
//   ),
//   200 => array(
//     0 => array(
//       'Id' => 2,
//       'Product' => 'Test2',
//       'TypeId' => 200
//     ),
//     1 => array(
//       'Id' => 3,
//       'Product' => 'Test3',
//       'TypeId' => 200
//     )
//   )
// )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.   It worked. Believe Laravel doesnt query the database when using groupby and it looks into collection.   Laravel 4.2 helpers section doesnt mention about this function.Please post me any good links other than api doco that doesnt have examples.